# How to optimise my database with some fixed values (fields or a new table)?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a database for my users. 
Each of them can be **developper** AND/OR **manager** AND/OR **commercial**
No other role will be created in the futur.
To optimise my database, Should I create one table with the following boolean fields :

is_developper
is_manager
is_commercial

Or should a create another table "roles" and a N-N table to join them ?

Comment: I'd argue for `user_role` N-N as it is more flexible.

Comment: Can he/she be commercial but not manager and not developper(sic)